# Capitalization of variable names in config.js causing undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using all capitals and underscores for my environment variable names in the config.js(where I store my symbolic constants like file paths etc.) file in my node.js app.

`config.VARIABLE_NAME`, returns undefined.
`config.variableName`, works perfectly fine.

here is my config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    RAW_UPLOAD_PATH: '/path/to/uploads/',
    DIR_UPLOAD: '/path/to/uploads2/'
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: Config.js? Please precise which library/framework are you using

Comment: How are you exporting these variables from `config.js`

Comment: module.exports = a json with all the variables and values

Comment: Can you update the question with sample `module.exports = obj` in the question. The issue is likely that field names on that object are camel-cased I'm not sure.

Comment: Please also show the code that tries to load this config. Because given the code you show, ```const config = require(`some/path/to/config.js`);``` will work perfectly fine.